# How to limit image size on designer?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good day.
I'm creating an app in Xamarin, I come from an Android background, in Android Studio It was not necessary to set the component size manually because I could choose match_parent or wrap_content. is there something similar in Xamarin.Forms?

I have tried using Horizontal and Vertical Options but neither seems to works. The image simply doesn't fit. I guess it's because im trying to fit the image in a button.

As you can see below the size is incorrect 
[image: incorrect size when in button]
I've tried to set the Padding with no success whatsoever, using the button Padding or even with another StackLayout's Padding.
is there any other solution than using image component and setting a listener in it for the click?
[image: correct size when in img]

Comment: Have you tried HeightRequest and WidthRequest?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the Control you are looking to use is the `ImageButton`. With the VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions you should be able to center propertly the Control.

```
<ImageButton Source="blue-play-button.png"
             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

[image]

Hope this helps.-

Answer (score 1):

like pinedax said,you could use `ImageButton`,after you set **HorizontalOptions** and **VerticalOptions**,you could limit its size by **HeightRequest** and **WidthRequest**,**Aspect** property size the image within the bounds it is being displayed within (whether to stretch, crop or letterbox),you could also set a click listener in it like Button:

```
<ImageButton Source="play_button.png" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"  Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"></ImageButton>
```

in behind code:

```
private void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("clicked");
  }
```